# Codeigniter Image Gone after re-login in but still saved in database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I successfully uploaded a user photo in database and ('/uploads' folder) and was able to display but everytime I logged out then when i login again the image/photo disappears.

> logout

```
   public function logout()
{
    $newdata = array(
    'id'   =>'',
    'memberfname'  =>'',
    'memberlname'  =>'',
    'email'     => '',
    'image'     => '',

    'logged_in' => FALSE,
    );
    $this->session->unset_userdata($newdata );
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    $this->home();
}
```

> Controller

```
  public function editphoto($id){
  $data = array(

 "action" => base_url('/index.php/Memberlogincontroller/updatephoto/'.$id), 
            "data" => $this->db->get_where('member',array('id'=>$id))   
    );    

    $this->load->view('member/image', $data);
}

public function upload($id) {
     if ( (int)$id < 1)//$id is not an integer
{
    redirect('memberlogincontroller/member_view', 'refresh');
}
    $this->load->helper(array('form','file','url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $config_image = array(
        'upload_path'   => './uploads/',
        'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png',
        'max_size'      => '1024',
        'overwrite'     => true
       // 'max_width'     => '1024',
       // 'max_height'    => '768',

    );

    $this->load->library('upload', $config_image);

      if($this->form_validation->run()==false and empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'][0]))
      {
            $error = array(
                'error_image' => 'Please choose image to upload',
            );
        $this->load->view('member/image', $error);

        }elseif($this->form_validation->run()==true and empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'][0])){
        $error = array(
                'error_image' => 'Please choose image to upload',
        );
        $this->load->view('member/image', $error);
        }elseif($this->form_validation->run()==false and !empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'][0])){
            !$this->upload->data();
             $error = array(
                'error_image' => '',
        );
        $this->load->view('member/image', $error);
        }elseif($this->form_validation->run()==true and !empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'][0])){
             $this->upload->do_upload();
             $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
             $this->image->resize($data['upload_data']['full_path'], $data['upload_data']['file_name']);
             $profile = array(
                'image' => $data['upload_data']['file_name']    
        );
        $this->db->update('member',$profile,array('id'=>$id));          
        $this->session->set_userdata($profile); 
        redirect('index.php/memberlogincontroller/getMember/'.$id, 'refresh');       

        }
        } 


    public function image_resize($path,$file){
        $config_resize=array(
        'image_library' => 'gd2',
        'source_image' => $path,
        'maintain_ratio' => TRUE,
        'width'=> 75,
        'height'=>50,
        'new_image'=>'./uploads/thumb/'.$file
        );
        $this->load->library('image_lib',$config_resize);
        $this->image_lib->resize();

    }


    public function updatephoto($id){
    if ((int)$id < 1)//$id is not an integer
{
    redirect('memberlogincontroller/member_view', 'refresh');
}
else{
    $this->load->helper(array('form','file','url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $config_image = array(
        'upload_path'   => './uploads/',
        'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png',
        'max_size'      => '1024',
        'overwrite'     => true

       // 'max_width'     => '1024',
       // 'max_height'    => '768',

    );

    $this->load->library('upload', $config_image);

      if($this->form_validation->run()==false and empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'][0]))
        {
            $id = $this->session->userdata('id');
            $memberinfo = array(
                'error_image' => '',
            );
        $this->load->model('MemberloginModel');
        $memberinfo['memberinfo'] = $this->Memberloginmodel->getMember($id);
        $this->load->view('member/image',$memberinfo);


        }
        else
        {
             $this->upload->do_upload();
             $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
             $this->image_resize($data['upload_data']['full_path'], $data['upload_data']['file_name']);
             $id = $this->session->userdata('id');
             $this->db->where('id', $id);
             $query = $this->db->get('member'); 
    /*      foreach($query->result() as $row)
        {
            unlink('./uploads/'.$row->image);
            unlink('./uploads/thumb/'.$row->image);
        }        */  
            $data = array(
                'image' => $data['upload_data']['file_name']    
        );
        $this->db->update('member',$data,array('id'=>$id));          
        $this->session->set_userdata($data); 
        redirect('index.php/memberlogincontroller/getMember/'.$id, 'refresh');       
    }
    }
    }
```

> Model

```
class Memberloginmodel extends CI_Model{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('url','html','form'));
}
function login()
{
    $this->db->where('email',$this->input->post('email'));
    $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));


$query = $this->db->get('member');  /*i added 'member' table on db new members*/

       if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        foreach($query->result() as $rows)
        {
            //add all data to session
            $newdata = array(
                    'id'            => $rows->id,
                    'memberfname'   => $rows->memberfname,
                    'memberlname'   => $rows->memberlname,
                    'email'         => $rows->email,

                    'logged_in'     => TRUE
               );
        }
            $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
            return true;            
        }else{
            return false;
        }
 }

   public function add_user()
{
    $data = array(
        'memberfname'=>$this->input->post('memberfname'),
        'memberlname'=>$this->input->post('memberlname'),
        'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
        'password'=>md5($this->input->post('password')),

        );
    $this->db->insert('member',$data);
}

public function getMember($id)
{
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$query = $this->db->get('member');

if ($query->num_rows() !== 1)
{
    return FALSE;
}
return $query->row();
}
```

> upload image view

```
<form  action="<?php echo $action;?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

// echo $action, refer to memberlogincontroller/editphoto

<a href="#"><img height="200px" width="200px"src="<?php echo base_url().'/uploads/'.$this->session->userdata('image'); ?>"> 

<input type="file" name="userfile" />
    <br /><br />

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('id'); ?>"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  value="upload" />
</form>
```

> userprofile view page

```
<div class="description">
            <!--    <a href="#"><img height="200px" width="200px" src="<php echo base_url();?>uploads/no-avatar.jpg"></a>-->
                 <a href="#"><img height="200px" width="200px"src="<?php echo base_url().'/uploads/'.$this->session->userdata('image'); ?>"> 
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->session->userdata('image')
```

is not set yet in `$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);`!

```
foreach($query->result() as $rows)
    {
        //add all data to session
        $newdata = array(
                'id'            => $rows->id,
                'memberfname'   => $rows->memberfname,
                'memberlname'   => $rows->memberlname,
                'email'         => $rows->email,

                'logged_in'     => TRUE
           );
    }
```

In `$newdata` you should add 'image'

Comment: oh sorry about that i wasnt able to check it again. thank you.